# IOS uiview brightness change

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode7

I have two UIViews on my screen.  I need to do the following:

If I increase the first view's alpha value, the second UIView alpha value should decrease.  The reverse is also true.

Please show me an example of how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO friend! Can you post some sample code please?

Comment: How are you currently changing the alpha value of your first view?

Comment: Are both views in a single View ? What's your actual interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this can help you to start:

```
// Displays second view and hide first view.
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options: 0
                     animations:^{
                         myFirstView.alpha = 0.0f;
                         mySecondView.alpha = 1.0f;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }
];
```

The reverse case can be produced by reversing the alpha values.